# jQuery plugin definition

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

There's something about the "standard" jQuery plugin definition that I can't seem to understand, and it seems that no plugin tutorial out there explains it.
Most plugin definitions I've seen are something like:

```
(function($) {
    $.extend($.fn, {
        pluginName: function( options )
            ...
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Now, while I understand what the `function($) { ... }` part does (makes sure that jquery works with `$` even in noConflict mode, creates a "private" method etc), I don't get why the very first character is `(`, and it ends with `)(jQuery)`.

Is it needed to make plugins chainable? Can it be safely ignored?

**Edit**

Variation of the same definition:

```
;(function($) { // why is ; there?
```

Comment: Here's a hint: The pattern `(function(params) { ... })(args)` defines an anonymous function, and then calls it.

Comment: About the preceding semi-colon: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365172/javascript-semicolon-before-self-invoking-function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It simply defines an anonymous function and calls it right away, you can think of it like this:

```
var f = function($) { /* Code goes here, can use $ */ };
f(jQuery); // assings jQuery to $ parameter
```

Now if you combine those two statements into one, you get:

```
(function($) { /* Code goes here */ })(jQuery);
```

That's all it really does. Doing it with an anonymous function this way won't pollute the global scope with useless variable names, and lets you use the `$` symbol even in noConflict mode.

Answer (score 1):

The wrapping lines are to do with creating an anonymous function and then calling it. jQuery is passed and then aliased to $ such that your plugin will still work in jQuery noConflict mode ($ will not be defined). The anonymous function is so our plugin get's a local scope so we don't accidentally define any global variables as they are bad.

Another point as a jQuery Plugin developer myself, I wouldn't really suggest developing plugins using that code:
    $.extend($.fn, {
        pluginName: function( options )
            ...
    });

All this will do is just add a series of functions to the jQuery Object Prototype, so for instance you can call $('#el').pluginName(). This is fine if your plugin is extremely simple, but it can become quite difficult to maintain as your plugin is still defined in a procedural fashion rather than object oriented.

A better approach would be something like this:

```
$.pluginName = {
    init: function(){
        var myPlugin = $.pluginName;

        // Attach jQuery Object Prototype (fn function)
        $.fn.pluginName = myPlugin.fn;

        // Attach DomReady
        $(function(){
            myPlugin.domReady();
        });
    }
    domReady: function(){},
    fn: function(){
        // your jQuery object function
    }
});

// Initialise our Plugin
$.pluginName.init();
```

This approach also allows people to easily extend your plugin if it falls short in some area or fix code themselves without touching yours. For instance I could overwrite your fn function by doing this:
    $.pluginName.fn = fixedFnFunction();

This is great for community development. I also like it as it keeps what is in the jQuery Object Prototype to a minimum so less overhead.

I'm looking for the articles I used for reference about this and will post them when ready.

Comment: very useful info, although it wasn't exactly what I was asking here, +1

Answer (score 0):

the construct (..)(jQuery) is the closure used to "insert" inside the namespace "jquery"