# Semicolon before self-invoking function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the benefit of using semicolon before a self-invoking function in JavaScript? I saw this approach in few popular jQuery plugins and I'm curious to find if this is the next awesome thing in JavaScript that I don't know.

Comment: The semi-colon is placed in front of the left paren `(` in order to prevent the JavaScript interpreter from interpreting the parens as a function invocation operator.

Comment: @xantos for example fancybox: https://github.com/vanntastic/fancy-box/blob/master/jquery.fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.2.1.js

Comment: Smashing Magazine article using this for jquery plugin boilterplate:  http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/

Comment: @ZachL. I really liked that article. Thanks!

Answer (score 184, accepted):

If you concatenate two files with self-invoking functions together that look like this:

File A:

```
(function(){...A...})()
```

File B:

```
(function(){...B...})()
```

File A+B:

```
(function(){...A...})()(function(){...B...})()
```

You have two statements without separator. This happens when you cat files together and then minify them.

Now the author of file B puts a semicolon in front:

File B2:

```
;(function(){...B2...})()
```

And you'll get a working script:

```
(function(){...A...})();(function(){...B2...})()
```

Comment: Well, why should I prefer the semicolon in front of the self-invoking function rather than after it?

Comment: @7elephant 2 semi-colons don't hurt, but no semi-colons do, so it's a safety issue, especially relevant for larger projects

Comment: preventative medicine

Comment: Do you also include a semicolon at the beginning of each statement in case the previous statement doesn't end with one?

Comment: @Brandon No, only in front of the whole file. The statements inside the concatenated files should be separated by semicolons anyway to create valid JavaScript code.

Answer (score 32):

Self-invoking functions are surrounded by parentheses, and in JavaScript parentheses are overloaded to mean

1. Grouping expressions to override precedence: `(x + y) * z`
2. Function application : `f()`

Putting a semicolon before the function prevents the function from becoming an argument to whatever precedes it when the parentheses become confused with function application.

Consider

```
var x = 42

(function () { ... })()
```

is the same as

```
var x = 42(function () { ... })()
```

but

```
var x = 42

;

(function () { ... })()
```

is the same as

```
var x = 42;

(function () { ... })()
```

Comment: that is only when minified badly

Comment: @Neal, could you please explain.  I think minification is entirely orthogonal to this.

Comment: @Neal It's equivalent otherwise too: try replacing `...` with `return 1` then add the semi-colon after 42 and see the difference.

Comment: Very interesting.  I created a fiddle for what @Josh said so I could see for myself what happens: [http://jsfiddle.net/LK63x/](http://jsfiddle.net/LK63x/).

Comment: @Neal, Yeah.  The newlines have nothing to do with it as shown by http://jsfiddle.net/vZvfG/ .  Newlines only affect [restricted productions](http://aresemicolonsnecessaryinjavascript.com/) in JS: `return`, `this`, `++`, `--`, `break`, `continue`.

Comment: +1 though not all IIFEs are necessarily surrounded by parentheses. `!function(){}()` or `"invoke!",function(){}()` would work as well and would only need the preceding `;` if the code gets minified.

Comment: @patrick dw, Interesting.  I haven't seen that pattern in production code.

Answer (score 16):

*I* write *all* JavaScript in a semicolon-free style. When writing without semicolons at the end of every line, due to Automatic Semicolon Insertion (ASI), there are a few special cases that can "be confusing" at first:

1. *Starting a top-level expression with an operator*, a `(` (open parenthesis) in this case, which *like most other operators*, can *continue* the previous expression and thus suppresses the "automatic insertion of a semicolon". (This generally *only occurs* when using a self invoking function.)
2. Just kidding about #2: there isn't one! (Learn only one rule and you too can enjoy life without extra semicolons ;-)

Since I write in a semicolon-free style I thus *always* write it as (where the function-expression can naturally span multiple lines):

```
;(FunctionExpression)()
```

In *my* case it isn't about "safety" or trying to "catch an error" (honestly, if your style is to use semi-colons and you forget a semi-colon, then you've *already created the error elsewhere* and writing a `;` at the start for "safety" is hogwash). No; in my case it is done for *consistency* with *knowledge* of my chosen style and "knowing" that *starting a line with an operator* can continue an expression from a previous line.

See [JavaScript: Semicolon Insertion (Everything You Need To Know)](https://web.archive.org/web/20120615060024/inimino.org/%7Einimino/blog/javascript_semicolons) for the details (it is by far the best article I have seen on the subject).

Happy coding.

Comment: You're asking for trouble, really, relying on what is essentially an mechanism to gloss over sloppy programming. The semicolons are there for a reason.

Comment: @thepeer No, no, I'm not really. Omitting semi-colons is not "sloppy coding". Please back up such unfounded claims; in my post I have explained what the "issue" is when writing in a semicolon-free style and provided a rule on how to write code that *never* has a problem with ASI. Then I explain why it is irrelevant to "safety" and provide a link to a resource covering the details (look up the `return` production in the link). On the other hand, the comment that provoked this response attacked my coding style and made a statement which I find to be unfounded. Not cool.

Comment: @thepeer While I have addressed different "safety" concerns in other questions about ASI, in this particular answer I make the claim that it is *incorrect and unsafe* to omit *any* semi-colon in a semicolon-required style - particularly because one is not *always* prepared for continued lines, as one (like me) who writes a semicolon-free style is. Thus there is no difference between the two approaches in terms of "safety". Now, the big *advantage* of semicolons is that many tools/formatters are confused if such are not used. This is *not* related to "sloppy coding", but relates to tooling.

Comment: @thepeer As for a real-world numbers on terms of the "safety" in code, I have only my own experience. In many, many years of JavaScript, I have been burnt by a semicolon-free code exactly once when I first ran into this construct. I have had *none* relating to semicolon "omission" since I started using rule #1 - that's pretty impressive, no? (I have been burnt by the `return` construct a few times but, ironically, that is *not* related to writing in a semicolon-free style. See the link in the article.)

Comment: There are other rules.  For example, `"undefined" === typeof (function () { return /*newline*/ 42; })()`.  See [restricted productions](http://es5.github.com/#x7.9.1) for more details.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Thanks for writing it out :) That production is covered in the linked article and is just as broken with/without the semicolon. It's an interesting production grammar itself and runs counter to the `;`-ends a statement view.

Comment: @pst, Restricted productions are not covered in your rule 1.  You need a rule 2.

Comment: @MikeSamuel No, I do not. It is *unrelated* to semicolons. One needs to "know" that even if ending every statement with a semicolon. As such, it is a flawed argument that rule #1 doesn't cover it.

Comment: @pst, `"undefined" === typeof (function () { return /*newline*/ 42; })()` is true precisely because a semicolon is inserted after the `return`.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Oh, I see what's confusing. I'm was intending that rule to cover the case of writing semicolon-free code for code that was *otherwise valid* with semicolons. In any case, this is well covered in the supplied resource - I keep saying it because it's a good read and will cover more than an SO answer is intended to - and is just as invalid with a semicolon.

Comment: @pst, Here's another case : if you tend to write shorthand like `condition && side_effect()` then `/foo/i.test(x) && sideEffect()` following `var x = 42` turns into the equivalent of `var x = 42 / foo / i.test(x) && sideEffect()`, so top level regular expressions are also problematic since they can be ambiguous with division operators.

Comment: @pst, Fair enough re restricted productions.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Touche. I guess I just "take binary operators for granted" :D (That regex case is extra tricky, but ick - side-effects in expressions? :-/)

Comment: @pst, Yeah.  `(` ambiguity is a grammar level ambiguity, while the `/` is a lexical ambiguity.  I do sympathize with your overall point -- since I started writing Go code, I've found that I appreciate some formulations of semicolon insertion.  This would not be a problem with JavaScript's semicolon insertion rules applied to a language with a regular lexical grammar, but JavaScript's weird tokenization rules do lead to more corner cases.

Comment: Re "ick - side-effects in expressions?", people who write a lot of bash tend to produce JS that looks like bash :)

Comment: @MikeSamuel Touche again. I must stop before I run out of points to give.

Comment: @pst I wasn't accusing *you* of sloppy coding; forgive me if that's how it read. I meant that the reason why the js parser automatically inserts semicolons was originally - like some other js features (undeclared variables becoming global is another) - because js was seen as a hack-ish language that should be forgiving of sloppy coding practises. I'm aware that there is a movement to make semicolon-free js more rigorous; I'm against it. In fact I wish strict mode would throw an error or at least a warning when a semicolon is omitted.

Comment: @user166390 Your rule 1 doesn't cover statements that begin with `[`. It's not quite so common, but something like this will also fail if you're relying on ASI: `var abc = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] /*newline*/ [ 'hello', 'world' ].forEach(function(it) { console.log(it) })`

Comment: Another issue here is that the leading semicolon may appear superfluous to readers as it only matters when someone adheres to the style you advocate. In other words, in code which places semicolons collinear with the statement they terminate extraneous semicolons are not an error.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the semi colon was triggering an error in Internet Explorer 8 (or at least that's what IETester said), and preventing the ui tabs from working properly.

The error message was `Invalid character in jquery.all.ui.js  Line: 1. Char: 1`.

I stumbled on the semi-colon completely by chance.
When I removed the `;` from the `;(function($)` it worked, seemingly without side-effects or loss of functionality.
I am using Drupal, don't know whether this has anything to do with the matter.