# What is the meaning of such definition?

Tags: javascript, node.js

While looking via some modules sources for node.js I have found one having the following construction:

```
;(function(global){

    var a = // some definitions
    .. // code



})(typeof window === "object" ? window : this);
```

So what is the meaning to write:

1. semicolon in front of code?
2. to write (typeof window === "object" ? window : this); ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The semicolon is a safety measure for minifications (elaborated on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365172/semicolon-before-self-invoking-function)).

The second part of your question: `(typeof window === "object" ? window : this)` is checking whether the code runs in a browser. If window is actually defined, then we conclude it runs in a browser, if not it runs in node. Then we pass this environment (node.js or window) as a variable.

Comment: +1 The semicolon also hinders collisions between modules, if somebody helds to the style of writing with "Automatic Semicolon Insertion"...[citation needed]

Comment: @dollarVar no citation, but here is an example: `var a = 42 /*newline*/ (function(){})()` results in TypeError: number is not a function

Comment: @Tibos Ok, I throw something in: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12. Look at the NOTE...seems like `IIFE` is not that welcome by ECMA :/ About the `ASI` thing here: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8 (scroll up to the last *The Source*;)